# Symbolic link in Log structured file system

Tags: operating-system

I am doing a project on Log structure File system,I am mid way doing the project,Have created the inodes for the normal file and directory ,now i want to work on symbolic link.

Here is the structure for my inode.

int8_t is_active;

```
/* inode no. of the file */
uint16_t inode_number;

/* the most up-to-date version id */
uint8_t latest_version_id;

/* Details about the direct block */
BlockInfo direct_block[4];

/* Details about the indirect block */
BlockInfo indirect_block;

/* The type, permissions, etc. */
unsigned long inode_mode;

/* The user id */
//unsigned short uid;

/* The group id */
//unsigned short gid;

/* The number of links to the inode */
unsigned short number_of_links;

/* The size of the file, in bytes.
 * If it is a directory file, this will contain the number of
 * immediate children in the directory.
 *
 * If it is a regular file, it will contain the actual file size*/
unsigned long int file_size;

/* The number of blocks used by the inode */
unsigned long number_of_blocks;

/* The creation time of the file */
struct timeval creation_time;

/* The modification time of the file */
struct timeval modification_time;

struct timeval access_time;
```

Can Anybody help me in going about creating symbolic links.

Answer (score 0):

A symlink is a regular file with the pathname to the target contained in it.  Use a mode bit to cause the filesystem code to read the link and do the redirect on open, create, unlink, etc.